# How to propagate sub project's conditional macro definitions to parent project?

Tags: cmake

I'm looking for a way to reflect sub project's preprosessor macro definition to the parent project.

I wrote minimal and executable example to demonstrate the issue:

Let's say I have the following files:
The parent project has CMakeLists.txt and parent.cpp in the current directoy.
The sub project has CMakeLists.txt, sub.hpp, and sub.cpp in the `sub` directory. It is third party's project (e.g. some open source software)

```
./CMakeLists.txt .......A
  parent.cpp     .......B
  sub/CMakeLists.txt ...C
      sub.hpp ..........D
      sub.cpp ..........E
```

The parent project's CMakeLists.txt (A) is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(parent)

add_subdirectory(sub)
include_directories(sub)
add_executable(parent parent.cpp)
```

And parent.cpp (B) is

```cpp
#include "sub.hpp"

int main() {
    print();
}
```

It simply calls sub's print() function.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

The sub project's CMakeLists.txt (C) is

```
project(sub)

message(STATUS ${OPTION1})

add_executable(sub sub.cpp)

if (OPTION1)
    target_compile_definitions(sub PUBLIC PP_OPTION1)
endif ()
```

The preprosessor macro `PP_OPTION1` is conditionally defined by cmake option `OPTION1`.

sub.hpp (D) is

```cpp
#include <iostream>

inline void print() {
#if defined(PP_OPTION1)
    std::cout << "PP_OPTION1 set" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "PP_OPTION1 not set" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

It refers to PP_OPTION1 and chooses output message.

sub.cpp (E) is the same as parent.cpp (B).

```cpp
#include "sub.hpp"

int main() {
    print();
}
```

When I execute the following command in the current directory:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DOPTION1=ON ..
cmake --build .
```

Then two binaries `parent` and `sub` are built.
When I execute parent, then I got

```
PP_OPTION1 not set"
```

When I execute sub/sub, then I got

```
PP_OPTION1 set"
```

This is because PP_OPTION1 is only set for sub project.
Is there any good way to reflect the PP_OPTION1 definition to the parent project?

I can achieve it using `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-DPP_OPTION1"`. It could be a workaround. But if conditionally defined preprosessor macro by the cmake option is automatically reflected to the parent project, it is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you attach this kind of info to a target linked to the targets that are supposed to gain access to this info. The fact that you're building an *executable* instead of a library in the subdir means you'll have to introduce an additional target for this.

**sub/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# attach info to interface target
add_library(sub-interface INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(sub-interface INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

if (OPTION1)
    target_compile_definitions(sub-interface INTERFACE PP_OPTION1)
endif ()

add_executable(sub sub.cpp)

# add info of sub-interface target
target_link_libraries(sub PRIVATE sub-interface)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(parent)

add_subdirectory(sub)

add_executable(parent parent.cpp)

# add info of sub-interface target (compile define + include dir)
target_link_libraries(parent PRIVATE sub-interface)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your anser is what I wanted to know.